# Windows 10 update failing on surface pro 7

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-surface

I have been trying to install 1909 for the last few days and I cannot for whatever reason. I have tried using cmd to stop/start the server settings and delete the download folder and tried the update assistant but that yielded error code `00x900700c1`.

[image: IMG:]

I cannot determine what is causing my updates to fail.

Log file info shown in Event Viewer:
- System

- Provider

  [ Name]
  [ Guid]  {0b7a6f19-47c4-454e-8c5c-e868d637e4d8}

  EventID 0

  Version 0

  Level 4

  Task 0

  Opcode 0

  Keywords 0x800
- TimeCreated

  [ SystemTime]  2020-05-15T18:11:04.829275300Z

  EventRecordID 82

  Correlation
- Execution

  [ ProcessID]  13112 
  [ ThreadID]  14968 
  [ ProcessorID]  0 
  [ KernelTime]  5 
  [ UserTime]  0

  Channel

  Computer DB-Surface7

  Security

  - ProcessingErrorData

  ErrorCode 15003

  DataItemName

  EventPayload 2A00200045004E00440020002A00200053006500720076006900630065002000650078006900740020004500780069007400200063006F006400650020003D002000300078003200340030003000300031000000

Comment: It is normally best in the "cannot update" issues to work through the steps in the Microsoft Windows Update troubleshooting article:   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/windows-update-troubleshooting

Comment: Windows Update generates a log when an update cannot be installed.  Please provide the relevant information from that log.  Without that information your question is unclear and cannot be answered.  There is a tool specifically designed to troubleshoot feature updates not being able to be installed.

Comment: Log info added to post. What tool is needed? I have already checked that website also and none of the suggestions have helped.

Comment: I saw this:  "For some others Feature Update to Windows 10, version 1909 Fail with Error Code 0x800f081f or 0xc1900223. There is a various reason that causes Windows 10 update installation problem, some common reason are the downloaded update file is corrupted or because of a non-compliant device driver or software"   Run the driver update process for the Surface including BIOS. For the Surface, Windows update does drivers including BIOS.

Comment: What about using in-place upgrade with image? That solved similar issues in the past for me!

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost make a backup of your current state just in case something goes wrong.

If you just want to install the 1909 or the next major release of Windows 10 I would recommend using the In-Place Upgrade functionality with the [Windows Media Tool or Image](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10). This typically bypasses issues with the Windows 10 update service and also fixed them after installation for me.

If you want to fix the underlying issue with the Update Service, often clearing the update cache helps. Something [like that](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/how-to-clear-windows-update-cache/f397d5f6-1fe0-4f41-9d25-862fb45f918c?auth=1) brought up a quick Google search. There might be better ways to clear the cache but you can easily find different approaches online.